# How to generate understandable graph from Jtl File in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have done the below set up in user.properties. I have Jtl files which is of format the csv.

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

I am loading the JTL files and getting graph report. which has Average, Median, 95% and 90% Line, Min and Max.

```
X- Axis --> calls that is made and 
Y-Axis --> milliseconds..
```

I want more info that how many users active and how many error %.

No. of Active Users, Response time, Error %, Transaction per second can we get the details in the graph

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML dashboard generator in your scenario. Have a look at the [link](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and check if it suffice your requirement. Then, follow the procedure to generate it.

You can use it in 2 ways:-

1. Generation from an existing sample CSV log file
2. Generation after load test
   Both are mention in the jmeter dashboard link provided.